# GitHub actions: How to switch conditionally a run command?

Tags: workflow, jobs, github-actions

I have created a workflow that contains this 2 jobs:

```
  build-and-test-with-Java-8-and-later:
    name: Build -> Test (JVM ${{ matrix.java }}, ${{ matrix.architecture }}, ${{ matrix.os }})
    strategy:
      fail-fast: true
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest, macOS-latest, windows-latest]
        java: [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
        architecture: [x32, x64]
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK ${{ matrix.java }}
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: ${{ matrix.java }}
          architecture: ${{ matrix.architecture }}  
      - name: Build and test
        run: mvn -B clean test -Dproject_jdk_version=${{ matrix.java }} -DskipTests=false --file pom.xml

  build-and-test-with-Java-15-ea:
    name: Build -> Test (JVM ${{ matrix.java }}, ${{ matrix.architecture }}, ${{ matrix.os }})
    strategy:
      fail-fast: true
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest, macOS-latest, windows-latest]
        java: [15-ea]
        architecture: [x32, x64]
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK ${{ matrix.java }}
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: ${{ matrix.java }}
          architecture: ${{ matrix.architecture }}  
      - name: Build and test
        run: mvn -B clean test -Dproject_jdk_version=15 -DskipTests=false --file pom.xml
```

... And I would like to merge this 2 jobs in a unique job that switch the run element when iterated ${{ matrix.java }} variable contains the '-ea' suffix. in particular I would like to create something like this:

```
  build-and-test-with-Java-8-and-later:
    name: Build -> Test (JVM ${{ matrix.java }}, ${{ matrix.architecture }}, ${{ matrix.os }})
    strategy:
      fail-fast: true
      max-parallel: 10
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest, macOS-latest, windows-latest]
        java: [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15-ea]
        architecture: [x32, x64]
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK ${{ matrix.java }}
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: if${{ matrix.java }}
          architecture: ${{ matrix.architecture }}  
      - name: Build and test
        if: ${{ matrix.java }} != '15-ea'
        run: mvn -B clean test -Dproject_jdk_version=${{ matrix.java }} -DskipTests=false --file pom.xml
      - name: Build and test
        if: ${{ matrix.java }} == '15-ea'
        run: mvn -B clean test -Dproject_jdk_version=15 -DskipTests=false --file pom.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the available [function](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#operators) from Githu Actions.

In your case this would work:

```
- name: Build and test
   if: contains(matrix.java, '15-ea')
   run: mvn -B clean test -Dproject_jdk_version=${{ matrix.java }} -DskipTests=false --file pom.xml
```